# Mechanistic Explanations for Electron Degeneracy Pressure

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle

Most explanations of electron (or any fermion) degeneracy pressure cite Pauli's exclusion principle for fermions. I believe such explanations tell us why we *should believe* such phenomena exist, but they don't explain the underlying mechanism at play. Is there any ‘mechanistic’ explanation for fermion degeneracy pressure? Would delving into QFT provide such an explanation?

By a 'mechanistic' explanation, I roughly mean one that appeals to actual physical, local interactions among actual physical entities, without allowing some principles to do all the heavy-lifting.

Comment: There is _no possibility_ for a mechanistic explanation. This is much worse than the famous video clip of a reporter wanting a mechanistic "contact forces" kind of explanation of magnetism that Feynman brilliantly pointed out is the opposite: electromagnetism of the long distance field explanation is the reason why we have contact forces in the first place. Similarly, there is no possibility to explain _degeneracy_ pressure, because there is no way for this pressure to magically disappear between different types of particles.

Comment: But the underlying mechanism _is_ the exclusion principle, so I cannot see what you are asking.

Comment: I think he might mean, what particle mediates the forces in degeneracy pressure? I wonder this myself.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent, such an explanation has been provided since 2019. You can find the paper in my answer.

Comment: Are you trying to understand how we get from the Pauli exclusion principle to a pressure, or are you seeking to explain the pressure without the exclusion principle at all?

Comment: @Andrei I commented in your post below, but the most important one is that your post is not a mechanistic explanation as the OP stated he wanted.

Comment: There is a local theory of fermions in QFT, see https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.04553 and https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.14003

Comment: @nielsnielsen degeneracy pressure is a property of the underlying quantum field itself and is not mediated by a force boson. In short, because there is only one quantum field for all the electrons, exciting each new electron onto the (even in the non-interacting case) field incurs more and more resistance coming from fermion statistics alone.

Comment: I understand the down-votes, but honestly I'm not sure if there's a way to make it much clearer. @Sten I think it's the latter. The only 'explanation' I've seen for the exclusion principle is basically a reductio argument; if you assume that two fermions can occupy the same state, then we have an absurd situation where Psi = 0. naturallyinconsistent I have no intention to assume that there is a mechanistic explanation. But I'm not sure what evidence you have for the claim that there's 'no possibility' for such an explanation. It's a pretty strong claim.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent But your last comment is quite helpful. Now I see my use of the word 'mechanistic' was not as clear as it should be. Explaining a force in terms of particle exchange would be a paradigmatic example of a mechanistic explanation. But I'm open to other kinds of 'mechanism' for the same phenomenon.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent A mechanistic explanation, as I understand it, is one in which the behavior of a system is explained in terms of more fundamental elements interacting with one another causally or otherwise. Those 'more fundamental elements' may or may not be force carrying particles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a classical explanation of the electron's spin and of Pauli's exclusion principle in this paper:

Cetto, A.M., de la Peña, L. & Valdés-Hernández, A. Proposed physical explanation for the electron spin and related antisymmetry. Quantum Stud.: Math. Found. 6, 45–53 (2019). https://doi.org/10.1007/s40509-017-0152-8

The article can also be found on arxiv:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.08674.pdf

The explanation is provided in the context of the theory of stochastic electrodynamics which is in fact the classical theory of electromagnetism which takes into account the zero-point field (the field responsible for the Casimir force).

The paper reads (page 10):

"The calculations presented here confirm the physical picture of the spin of
the electron as a helicoidal motion (a zitterbewegung) around the local mean
trajectory, adding an effective structure to the originally pointlike particle."

"Further, for a bi- or multielectron system, consideration of the permanent presence of the background field resonantly connecting the particles serves to unveil the persistent mystery of the physics behind the spin-statistics association. The mediation of the zpf turns out to have a definite role in fixing the statistics. "

Comment: I am quite happy to accept spin as classical and zitterbewegung and so forth, but 1) this paper assumes quite a lot of quantum stuff, vectors in Hilbert spaces, commutation relations, etc 2) Equation (9) is just most insane and visually asserts that a fundamental const is some summation, when in fact it should be trying to say that a fixed size of spin half is equivalent to that summation, 3) SED is not mainstream physics 4) This is not at all a mechanistic explanation as the OP wanted 5) It is way too handwavy to even be an explanation—it should explain g-factor if it is a good theory of spin

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent, at page 2 of the paper there is a lot of discussion about the derivation of g-factor. Check also the paper "Emergence of quantization: The spin of the electron". SED is not a different theory from classical electrodynamics (which is mainstream). It is just Maxwell's theory applied to the real conditions in our universe, where this zero-point field exists. The OP asked for a local theory, and classical electromagnetism is certainly local. Regarding equation 9 I think you should check the derivation of Planck's constant in SED.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent, here: "The Contrasting Roles of Planck's Constant in Classical and Quantum Theories" - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.01616.pdf you can read about the way Planck's constant appears naturally in classical electromagnetism.

Comment: Thanks! Although this may not offer a 'mechanistic' explanation, it looks like this is the closest thing to what I was looking for. The math involved in it is beyond me, but it's interesting that at least some people are trying to figure out the physical mechanism behind quantum spin.